# 404s after updating to systemjs-angular-loader.js

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am updating my Angular project and decided to remove all instances of `moduleId: module.id`, as the docs have instructed me to here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/change-log.html

> All mention of moduleId removed. "Component relative paths" cookbook
>   deleted (2017-03-13)
>
> We added a new SystemJS plugin (systemjs-angular-loader.js) to our
>   recommended SystemJS configuration. This plugin dynamically converts
>   "component-relative" paths in templateUrl and styleUrls to "absolute
>   paths" for you.
>
> We strongly encourage you to only write component-relative paths. That
>   is the only form of URL discussed in these docs. **You no longer need to
>   write @Component({ moduleId: module.id }), nor should you.**

Before removing `moduleId: module.id`, I did the following steps:

1. Downloaded the systemjs-angular-loader.js file and put it in my src folder (same level as systemjs.config.js)
2. Added `loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'` to my systemjs.config.js file (tried to paste more code but it wouldn't format for some reason)
3. Updated systemjs version in package.json file: `"systemjs": "0.20.12",`

After following those steps and removing `moduleId: module.id` from my component, as the docs clearly say I should do, I got the following error:

> GET http://localhost:3000/checklists.component.html 404 (Not Found)

Here is what that component code looks like now:

```
@Component({    
    selector: 'checklists',
    templateUrl: 'checklists.component.html'    
})
```

Why am I getting a 404 on my html file? Did I miss a step?

Comment: Try adding `./` in front of the templateUrl. -> `'./checklists.component.html'`

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks!